# All info of last item is not showing in compose extension search of msteams app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We are working on search compose extensions to search our data with two commands (items). User is unable to see all info of the last item by scrolling bottom in channel scope. But working fine in personal scope. If we use one command that is also working fine. Take a look at the screenshot linked below.

[image: search personal scope]
[image: search channel scope]
[image: search channel scope with one command]

manifest code like below

```
"commands": [
        {
          "id": "search-ideas",
          "title": "Ideas",
          "type": "query",
          "description": "Search Item 1",
          "initialRun": true,
          "fetchTask": false,
          "context": ["compose"],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "term",
              "title": "search",
              "description": "Search",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "search-campaigns",
          "title": "Campaigns",
          "type": "query",
          "description": "Search",
          "initialRun": true,
          "fetchTask": false,
          "context": ["compose"],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "term",
              "description": "Search  here",
              "title": "search",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Could you please let us know if you are facing this issue only if you have two commands?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT yes, We are facing this for two commands only. One command is working fine.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Works fine with two commands in personal scope also. Only problem in Channel scope only with two commands.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I have added 3 screenshots in the description. Have a look.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Could you please create a bug for this?

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue. We are raising a bug for this. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Unfortunately we do not have any update as of now. We have brought it to the notice of engineering team and they are looking into it. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. We have verified the fix and it is working fine now.